# Why do we need the pthread_join () function

Tags: linux

Why do we need the pthread_join () function (why, not what it does)? If we have two threads (one running, the other waiting), then why do two threads if one can do the same?

Comment: Because two threads can do two things at the same time. Thread A starts thread B and they both do two things. Then thread A needs data from thread B, so it waits for thread B to finish and supply the data. Enter `pthread_join`. If you have a specific scenario that you are wondering about, please ask a specific question. As it is your question is very vague. Please see: [ask]

Comment: If your main function needs to do something while another thread does something then you have two choices:  End the whole program when the main function is finished even if the thread is not done or let the thread finish before ending the program.  If you want to let the thread finish, either you need to wait for it to finish by calling join or call detach so that its fate isn't tied to the main function.